# R: Ingest key value paired data as data frame or data table

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

Entry#1:

[{"X":380.125,"Y":2.15052E-06},{"X":380.74,"Y":2.53736E-06},{"X":381.355,"Y":8.36452E-07},{"X":381.971,"Y":8.18698E-07},{"X":382.586,"Y":2.82835E-06},...

Entry#2:

...

The dimensions of each of these entries (i.e. the number of Xs and Ys) is constant

Representing as a table:

380.125     2.15052E-06

380.74      2.53736E-06

and so on

How do I parse this into a data frame or data table?

Best

Dan

Comment: Is this JSON? If so there are contributed packages to transform the data into a data.frame. A google search would be your best option and if after trying them out you still have difficulties, update the post with the code you have used and a description of the problem.

Comment: Entry 1, entry 2, etc, are in a list, vector, what? Can you post the output of `dput(data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with package `rjson`. I create a vector of two strings copied from the question.

```
x <- c(
  '[{"X":380.125,"Y":2.15052E-06},{"X":380.74,"Y":2.53736E-06},{"X":381.355,"Y":8.36452E-07},{"X":381.971,"Y":8.18698E-07},{"X":382.586,"Y":2.82835E-06}]',
  '[{"X":380.125,"Y":2.15052E-06},{"X":380.74,"Y":2.53736E-06},{"X":381.355,"Y":8.36452E-07},{"X":381.971,"Y":8.18698E-07},{"X":382.586,"Y":2.82835E-06}]'
)

lst <- lapply(x, function(y) do.call(rbind.data.frame, rjson::fromJSON(y)))
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst)
#          X           Y
#2   380.125 2.15052e-06
#21  380.740 2.53736e-06
#3   381.355 8.36452e-07
#4   381.971 8.18698e-07
#5   382.586 2.82835e-06
#22  380.125 2.15052e-06
#211 380.740 2.53736e-06
#31  381.355 8.36452e-07
#41  381.971 8.18698e-07
#51  382.586 2.82835e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use strsplit and gsub to clean the input in the first step and than use tidyr to clean the dataframe , there are other solutions too.

```
## Example entry
entry1<-'[{"X":380.125,"Y":2.15052E-06},{"X":380.74,"Y":2.53736E-06},{"X":381.355,"Y":8.36452E-07},{"X":381.971,"Y":8.18698E-07},{"X":382.586,"Y":2.82835E-06}]'
## split the input
x<-strsplit(entry1,split = "}")
## throw out unecessary characters
x2<-gsub("[^0-9,E.-]", "", x)
## make a df
df<-as.data.frame(unlist(strsplit(x2,",,")))
## set x, y colum 
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(1,c("x","y"),",")
```